# Source for contest problems on systems of equation

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Can someone share me some sources on contest problems(or nice problems) on system of equations(with degree less than 2)
? I am studying from this book- A. Caminha Muniz Neto, An Excursion through Elementary Mathematics, Volume I. I want to keep revising from one of its chapters.

Comment: System of equations as in linear equations, or higher degree equations(like quadratics)? Only two equations, or more than two? Please specify a little more on what you are looking for; it is very likely that most of us don't have the book you are referring to.

Comment: sorry.It must involve up to the 2nd degree